# Can an Echo Knight's Echo use a weapon with two hands if the Knight is grappling?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, grapple, echo-knight

I am about to play an Echo Knight in a game, and have been doing my research. The gist of my understanding is that Echoes are unable to make grappling checks, and I am prepared to work with this. The knight, on the other hand, is still able to make grappling checks.

Grappling requires a free hand, and two-handed weapons require two hands to make an attack with them. When an Echo Knight makes an attack, the attack can originate from the Echo's space. If an Echo and the Knight both are wielding a two-handed weapon, and the Knight successfully grapples an opponent, are the Echo's hands considered free to make a two-handed weapon attack?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag since you mentioned the Echo Knight and described exactly the sort of shenanigans that come into play when playing with one.

Answer (score 3):

### You cannot attack with a two-handed weapon while grappling

The relevant text of the EK feature is:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn, **any attack you make with that action can originate from** your space or the echo's space. You make this choice for each attack.

It is still you making the attack, it only originates from the EKs space. Since you cannot attack with a two handed weapon while grappling (which uses up one of your hands), you also cannot do so from the EKs space.

Comment: Unless you have more than 2 hands, :)

Comment: @Toddleson, true, a Thri-Kreen Echo Knight might be able to do it, but it's not an official race (I think)